# Return true if any value in an specific key inside a jsonb array exists

Tags: postgresql

The rows in my table look like

```
 facility | events
----------+---------------------------------------------------------------
  1       | [{ "id" : "1", "count" : "4", "severity" : "bad" }, { "id" : "3", "count": "4", "severity" : "good"}]
```

I want to get all the rows who have a `severity = bad`

I tried

select facility, events::jsonb @> '"severity"' as bad from tbl limit 10;

and I got (same data as before)

```
 facility | bad
----------+-------
  1       | f
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can get it by using [jsonb_array_elements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-json.html) function and the [->>](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-json.html) operator.

> ```
> create table test (facility int, data jsonb);
>
> insert into test values 
> (1, '[{ "id" : "1", "count" : "4", "severity" : "bad" }, { "id" : "3", "count": "4", "severity" : "good"}]'),
> (2, '[{ "id" : "2", "count" : "4", "severity" : "good" }, { "id" : "3", "count": "4", "severity" : "good"}]'),
> (3, '[{ "id" : "3", "count" : "4", "severity" : "good" }, { "id" : "3", "count": "4", "severity" : "bad"}]');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT t1.facility, obj->>'severity' severity
> FROM   (SELECT facility, jsonb_array_elements(data) obj
>         FROM   test) t1
> WHERE  obj->>'severity' = 'bad'
> ```
>
> ```
> facility | severity
> -------: | :-------
>        1 | bad     
>        3 | bad
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=b2697c44daf36945400ce9e5f7698e1c)*

In case there is more than one `"severity" : "bad"` for the same facility you could avoid duplicates using DISTINCT.

> ```
> create table test (facility int, data jsonb);
>
> insert into test values 
> (1, '[{ "id" : "1", "count" : "4", "severity" : "bad" }, { "id" : "3", "count": "4", "severity" : "good"}]'),
> (2, '[{ "id" : "2", "count" : "4", "severity" : "good" }, { "id" : "3", "count": "4", "severity" : "good"}]'),
> (3, '[{ "id" : "3", "count" : "4", "severity" : "bad" }, { "id" : "3", "count": "4", "severity" : "bad"}]');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT distinct t1.facility, obj->>'severity' severity
> FROM   (SELECT facility, jsonb_array_elements(data) obj
>         FROM   test) t1
> WHERE  obj->>'severity' = 'bad'
> ORDER BY t1.facility
> ```
>
> ```
> facility | severity
> -------: | :-------
>        1 | bad     
>        3 | bad
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=859648bd4b7f36ec79ffd66d82a77130)*